# Link a MSVC compiled DLL in a MinGW-built project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, mingw

Given two C++ projects:

1. a **Win32** C++ project compiled as a x86 *DLL* under **Visual Studio** 2015
2. a **Qt** *GUI* application using `Desktop Qt 5.5.1 MinGW 32 bit` Kit.

What I'm trying to do is to link the first one in the second one. A MWE follows.

#### DLL header file: libxspectra.h

```
namespace XSpectra
{
  #define LIBXSPECTRA_EXPORTS // already defined into Project Properties
  #ifdef LIBXSPECTRA_EXPORTS
  #define LIBXSPECTRA_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  #define LIBXSPECTRA_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif

  LIBXSPECTRA_API int fnlibxspectra(void);
  LIBXSPECTRA_API int gnara(void) { return 7; };
  int foo() { return 1; };
  int bar();
}
```

#### DLL source file: libxspectra.cpp

```
#include "libxspectra.h"

namespace XSpectra
{
  LIBXSPECTRA_API int fnlibxspectra(void)
  {
    return 42;
  }

  int bar()
  {
    return 6;
  }
}
```

#### Qt source file: main.cpp

```
#include "libxspectra.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  XSpectra::foo();
  XSpectra::bar();
  XSpectra::gnara();
  XSpectra::fnlibxspectra();
  return 0;
}
```

#### Qt application build log

> error: undefined reference to XSpectra::bar()
>
> error: undefined reference to _imp___ZN8XSpectra13fnlibxspectraEv

While `foo()` and `gnara()` links correctly.

#### A few notes

1. I know the problem is not strictly Qt-related, but it's a matter of different compilation toolchains, a field where I'm a real novice. I'm actually asking for advices on this way.
2. If I comment the `#define LIBXSPECTRA_EXPORTS`, Visual Studio's Intellisense still marks it as defined, dll compiles, but the behaviour of external application's build process changes. The following error arises:

> error: function 'int XSpectra::gnara()' definition is marked dllimport

Comment: I don't think this is possible - the only toolchain I'm aware of that can do this is clang / llvm. MinGW is not ABI compatible with MSVC.

Comment: show -part of the Qt pro file please.

Comment: we don't matter about Qt since the problem is related to a generic C++ project built with MinGW toolchain. btw I'm going to edit the title to highlight this fact.

Comment: Check out what "name mangling" and "ABI" mean in the context of C++. In short, mixing output of different compilers is generally not possible. The difference with `foo()` and `gnara()` is that they are defined in the header file (though not properly made inline). The definition of the `LIBSPECTRA_API` macro is correct, but it must be used on all symbols to be exported, like `fnlibxspectra()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only link MSVC compiled C DLLs with MinGW, and only on 32-bit Windows. The MinGW linker can link directly to the DLL (if the functions are properly exported and not only available through an import library) or the usual import library. See [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/gendef/) and [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/Answer%20generation%20of%20DLL%20import%20library/) for how to generate a MinGW import library from a DLL.

You'll do it just like with MSVC (compile the dll with the functions marked `dllexport`, and compile the code using the dll with the functions marked `dllimport`, or use a `.def` file or something). Remember you need to export C functions, which means they need to be marked `extern "C"`.

I would strongly suggest though, making the code compatible with MinGW, and just compile everything with that. Or use the MSVC version of Qt.